# What is skb->priority in linux? When is it used?

Tags: linux, embedded, qos

I am trying to understand a QoS implementation on an embedded system. Is this a kernel level prioritization for QoS?

Answer (score 2):

The `skb->priority` field is meant to be used for QoS purposes by the packet scheduler and classifier layer (if enabled). See http://vger.kernel.org/~davem/skb.html